# Why does my function still return a promisse in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

My function which gets the values is returning a promise which I don't know how to wait for resolve. My failed code:

```js
const [rednderSaves, setRenderSaves] = React.useState([])
  const saveRenders = async () => {
    var data = await JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("connections"))
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      data[i].data = await JSON.parse(await data[i].data)
    }
    setRenderSaves(data)
  }
{saveRenders().then(rednderSaves.map(save => {
                return <Text key={Date.now()}>{save.name}</Text>
}))}
```

This overcomplicated thing STILL RETURNS A PROMISE. I have been scratching my head for the last 4 hours, please someone finally help. Thanks in advance

Comment: have a look on promise chaining. may be it will help!. not sure! what are you trying to do. If possible elaborate the question.

Comment: I already did, everything about it says that my code should work.....

Comment: try this . ```rednderSaves.length?rednderSaves.map(save => {
                return <Text key={Date.now()}>{save.name}</Text>
}):null```

Comment: Text does not get diplayed

Comment: in place of this ```<Text key={Date.now()}>{save.name}</Text>``` use ```<div>Testing</div>```. does it work

Comment: Tried that but with console.log, nothing gets logged

Comment: I have checked below answer working for me. can you provide your code if possible. one more thing you need to do the api call in useEffect as suggested below by buzzato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chained `then` always returns another promise. the proper way would to load your data at `useEffect` lifecycle correctly.

```
const [renderSaves, setRenderSaves] = React.useState([])
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const saveRenders = async () => {
      const data = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("connections"))
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i].data = JSON.parse(data[i].data)
      }
      setRenderSaves(data)
    }

    saveRenders()
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <>
      // ... content
      { renderSaves.map(save => <Text key={Date.now()}>{save.name}</Text>) }
    </>
  )
```

Comment: fwiw don't use `var`, use `const` or `let`. also `JSON.parse` doesn't return a promise for you to await.

Comment: renderSaves will be an empty array initially. there should be a condition

Comment: Ok, works, but I will be adding to the database as we go, So how do I deal with that?

Comment: @AndrewNedoma it depends what you mean as `we go`. that maybe would be more suitable to another question. if you mean that database may change and you want to listen to it than some socket implementation would be necessary. if you have some form that submit a request than at a success response you would update your data.

Comment: @Vibhav you would need a safe condition if `renderSaves` may not be an array at some point. an empty array would return another empty array which is acceptable for react afaik. nevertheless you can add some safe guard condition to avoid some crash if some inconsistency comes up.

Comment: @AndrewNedoma if you feel that answers your question you could consider it to mark as accepted answer or Vibrah's for that matter. and you can consider upvoting an answer if it feels it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const [rednderSaves, setRenderSaves] = React.useState([])
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    saveRenders() 
  },[])
  const saveRenders = async () => {
    var data = await JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("connections"))
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      data[i].data = await JSON.parse(await data[i].data)
    }
    setRenderSaves(data)
  }
   return (
    <>
     {
      rednderSaves.length?rednderSaves.map(save => (
       <Text key={Date.now()}>{save.name}</Text>
      )):
     null
     }
    </>
)
```